# Не видит новое пространство имён (C# xamarin forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin

При создании новой папки не могу обратиться к ресурсам в ней через using. Например создаю папку (Helpers), и обратится (using GenTree.Helpers) не могу.
Выскакивает такое предупреждение : (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: namespace - это не папка, а заданное значение в файле .cs. Другими словами у вас может быть все намешано в одной папке, но иметь разные namespace, или лежать файл в папке Helpers, но namespace будет как `namespace GenTree`. Так что смотрите именно значение в файле, а не название папки. Папки тут так, чисто удобство...

Comment: Создавайте классы прямо из студии, вместе с папками, она автоматом пропишет нужный неймспэйс с учётом названия папки. Хотя и руками это не сложно реализовать.